# How to specify z axis range and add add circle or ellipse in 3D plot in R

Tags: r

3-D graphing with Google(http://www.r-bloggers.com/3-d-graphing-with-google/)
(mu1=0 mu2=0 sigma1=1 sigma2=1 pho=0)

```
exp((-1/2)*(x^2+y^2))/(2*pi)  from -3 to 3
```

The rotate plot will be showd from google. The profile was a circle.

Dear Prof. Bolker [gave me the R code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24169023/980833):

```
library("emdbook")
library("rgl")
curve3d(dmvnorm(c(x,y),mu=c(0,0),Sigma=diag(2)),
     sys3d="rgl",front="line",back="line",
     xlim=c(-3,3),ylim=c(-3,3))
```

How to specify z axis range and get the plot like google's plot?

If pho=0 then the profile parallel to XY plane was circle.If pho<>0 then the profile parallel to XY plane was ellipse. How to add circle or ellipse in 3D plot? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not native english so I don't get the problem. Can you specify a little more? What library are you using in R to draw the plot?

Comment: it would be a good idea to specify as precisely as you can which aspects of Google's plot you would like to mimic.

Comment: I could only help specifying z-axis range.
Add zlim parameter such as zlim=c(0, 0.15)

Comment: I had used zlim parameter,but can not get the plot like google.

Comment: @stata, "can not get the plot like google" is too vague.  You need to say **what precisely** about Google's plot you want to imitate, otherwise you and everyone else will continue to be frustrated by our inability to help you ...

Comment: @Bolker Sorry. Here is abbreviation. How to upload the jpg picture file in stackoverflow?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I fully understand your question but:

1/ I do not think rgl allow to specify z axis range (and curve3d seems to allow it only for xlim, ylim) so you probably need to do it by hand

2/ You can rescale axis in rgl using rgl.viewpoint : e.g., rgl.viewpoint(scale=c(1,1,0.1))

3/ You can draw circle or ellipse using:

```
    t <- matrix(seq(-pi/2,pi/2, len=50), 50, 50, byrow=TRUE)
    p <- matrix(seq(-pi, pi, len=50), 50, 50)

    r <- 10
    x <- r*cos(t)*cos(p)
    y <- r*cos(t)*sin(p)
    z <- r*sin(t)

    persp3d(x, y, z)
```